# How to pass from.serialize() and array value using ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajaxform

I'm using serialize to pass the value of 'form' from ajax to controller. The problem is my 'test' array is null did not pass the value from ajax to controller I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5. Please help thanks

But when I removed the model form the test array has a value and pass into controller. I need both parameters to pass into controller

```
var test = [];
test[0] = 1;
test[1] = 2;

function saveSelected() {
    var model = $('form').serialize();

     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("index", "order")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { model: model.serialize(), test: test },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, string[] test)
{
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `model` is a string as you've already serialized it, you can't serialize it again. With regard to the issue, the simplest way would be to put the `test` data in to hidden fields in the `form` HTML and then it automatically gets serialised for you

Comment: but my test is not part of my form. is theres another way how to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data: { model: model, test: JSON.stringify(test)}`

Comment: the value of test looks like this. 0 = [1,2] this is what i need 0=[1], 1=[2] and my model is null.

Comment: Welcome to the platform. Could you familiarize yourself with how things work a bit?
Your answer looks more like a comment.